# How to replace the text in a textarea by removing HTML tags on MVC EditorFor Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, editor, textarea

I have a field in my database called **emailhtml** where I save a plain text email string from a textarea called plaintext. I save the \n etc by using:

```
string test = plaintext.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

Now in my EditorFor form I want to be able to display the field with the include line breaks etc but I cannot seem to work out how to do so. I have tried:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.Campaign.OwnHtml.Replace("<br />",System.Environment.NewLine ), new {rows="20", cols="20"})
```

But this results in an **InvalidOperationException:**

*Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use as shown below as well :

```
@{
    var text = Model.Campaign.OwnHtml.Replace("<br />", System.Environment.NewLine);
}

@Html.TextArea("textArea", text, new { rows = "20", cols = "20" })
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you aren't allowed to call .Replace() inside your lambda expression there. You need to bind directly to a property.

Try adding another property to whatever class your 'c' corresponds to. For example:

```
public string OwnHtmlWithLineBreaks
{
    get
    {
        return OwnHtml.Replace("<br />", System.Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Then in your view, change your TextAreaFor line to the following, binding to the new computed property:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.Campaign.OwnHtmlWithLineBreaks, new { rows = "20", cols = "20" })
```

Comment: I know I could do this but with another text area and then have change in one populated in other but I am now doing this via jQuery: document.getElementById('Campaign_OwnHtml').textContent = "@Model.Campaign.OwnHtml.Replace("<html>","").Replace("</html>","").Replace("<body>","").Replace("</body>","").Replace("<br />","\\n")"; This is not replacing ' and " marks and for some reason

Comment: I also tried document.getElementById('Campaign_OwnHtml').textContent = "@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Campaign.OwnCampaign)" but this didnt work either

Comment: Are you saying you're trying to have live updates between two text boxes, one having HTML, the other having plain text?